# Symfony 2 - Adding error to form element on preSubmit event subscriber

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a preSubmit event in an event subscriber for a form, and for a specific case I want to add an error to a form field. My method within the subscriber is as follows:

```
public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)

{ 
  $sourceData = $event->getData();
  $form       = $event->getForm();
  $identifier = &$sourceData['identifier'];

  if ($identifier) {

    if ($this->identifierIsUrl($identifier)) {
      $parser     = $this->getIdParser();
      $identifier = $parser->getIdentifier($identifier);

      if (is_null($identifier)) {
        $form->get('identifier')->addError(new FormError('You have either entered an incorrect url for the source or it could not be parsed'));
      }
    }

    $event->setData($sourceData);
    }    
}
```

However when I print the form error in the view, it is empty. Is it possible to do this in a preSubmit event? Am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: Just a second, why do you need to store an error BEFORE submit? Why can't you use NotBlank constraint  onto your form?

Answer (score 9):

The issue is related to the `Symfony\Component\Form\Form::submit` method that removes all of the form field specific errors assigned after the `PRE_SUBMIT` event.

During `Form::submit` it iterates over all the forms child objects (which are also themselves `Form` objects as noted by the other answers) and calls their `submit` methods individually. Resulting in the form element errors that were added during the parent's `PRE_SUBMIT` event to be reset to an empty array.

This is why you can use `$form->addError()` in the parent `PRE_SUBMIT` event or set the form element to `error_bubbling  => true` and it will display as the parent form errors, but not to a specific form element.

Here's the example of what occurs without looking through the entire codebase for Symfony Forms.

```
class Form 
{

     public function addError($error) 
     {
          if($this->parent && $this->config->getErrorBubbling()) {
              $this->parent->addError($error); //element had error_bubbling => true, attach the error to the parent.
          } else {
              $this->errors[] = $error; //add it to the current object's errors array
          }
    }

    public function submit() 
    {
         $this->errors = array(); //resets the errors of the current object
         $this->preSubmitEvent();

         foreach($this->children as $child) {
             $child->submit(); //errors in child object are reset
         }
    }
}
```

So it results in

```
Form:
    submitMethod:
       preSubmitEvent
       children:
          submitMethod:
              preSubmitEvent
```

---

To get around the issue you can add a `PRE_SUBMIT` event directly to your form element to validate that element and add errors to it.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('identifier', Form\TextType::class);
    //...
    $builder->get('identifier')->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, [$this, 'validateIdentifier']);
}
```

Then alter your `onPreSubmit` method accordingly.

```
public function validateIdentifier(FormEvent $event)
{ 
    $identifier = $event->getData();
    $element = $event->getForm();
    if ($identifier) {
        if ($this->identifierIsUrl($identifier)) {
            $parser     = $this->getIdParser();
            $identifier = $parser->getIdentifier($identifier);

            if (null === $identifier) {
                $element->addError(new FormError('You have either entered an incorrect url for the source or it could not be parsed'));
            }
        }

        $event->setData($identifier);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible if you look at the [Form::submit()](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Form.php#L519), you'll see that the errors are reset **before** the `PRE_SUBMIT` data is dispatched. Also [Validation Listener](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Form.php#L519) doesn't reset the errors on the form, and the [Violation Mapper](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Extension/Validator/ViolationMapper/ViolationMapper.php) only **adds** Errors to the form. And AFIK there aren't any listeners that reset the form's errors. So maybe you're doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that errors are just not displayed in your layout.

To debug, make sure your form is actually made invalid by your custom check (*if you show your controller I may be able to help with actual code*).

If that is in fact your issue, you may want to add `error_bubbling => true` to your field definition.